# Ubuntu 16.04 Asus Mediatek MT7630E doesn't work

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, mediatek

I had this working on Elementary but then it stopped so I switched to Ubuntu and I still can not get this driver installed and working.

I followed this tutorial 
https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796

As well as using the same install file but sudo bash install. I keep getting this error and output:

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/alyson/Downloads/MT7630E-release/rt2x00 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic'
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/alyson/Downloads/MT7630E-release/btloader modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic'
cp -v firmware/*/* /lib/firmware/
'firmware/BT/mt76x0.bin' -> '/lib/firmware/mt76x0.bin'
'firmware/Wi-FI/MT7650E234.bin' -> '/lib/firmware/MT7650E234.bin'
cp rt2x00/mt7630e.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
cp btloader/mt76xx.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
depmod
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mt7630e': Required key not available
```

I am assuming this is a 16.04 issue, but I do not know enough to work around it or know how to find another driver. any help would be greatly appreciated ! :)

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules-in-ubuntu-16

Answer (score 2):

[This driver (on GitHub)](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E#installation) works pretty well for me:

**Installation**

You need kernel headers to build the driver

As an example, on Debian and derivatives, assuming you're on an amd64 system:

```
sudo apt install build-essential linux-headers-amd64
```

That's all for dependencies.

First give some file execution permission:

```
chmod u+x install test uninstall bpatch
```

Now to install it, run:

```
./install
```

To test it without installing, run:

```
./test
```

To uninstall, run:

```
./uninstall
```

To install with dkms:

```
sudo make dkms
```

The driver will automatically load at startup.